# How to access consume REST Web-Service with Silverlight (use Proxy?) without clientaccesspolicy.xml or crossdomain.xml

Tags: silverlight, web-services, cross-domain

If you want to access some REST web services with your Silverlight application, the third party Server(where the service is, you want to access) needs a clientaccesspolicy.xml or crossdomain.xml in the rootfolder.

But how do i consume or access a REST service, which responds with a xml file, with my Silverlight application but WITHOUT any clientaccesspolicy.xml or crossdomain.xml beeing on that server?

if i write the service url in the addressfield of my browser, i can access the service and see response in browser. u can access service with GET.

edit: i already assume, that i would have to use some kind of proxy, but how for a RESTful service? Is it a clientside or serverside proxy?

How to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SL security policy prevents you from accessing addresses on a different domain. So the solution is to create a proxy in the domain of your SL app that will forward requests to the web service you want.

Comment: I know about the proxy but only with soap (wsdl) Services. How to do it with a REST Service? I can't find any example how to access a rest service without a crossdomain.xml but with a proxy!

Comment: You have to code the proxy in your web project, not on the client side. That way your server running .NET (or Java or whatever) doesn't get hit with the Silverlight security restriction.

Comment: Yes, but what kind of proxy is it? If i would call a soap or wcf service i could use the tool SLsvcUtil.exe to generate Proxies from  service metadata documents. But i call a REST service.

Comment: You have to create it by hand, with an API sufficient to make all your calls.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct. I have created a Silverlight client library which is convenient for consuming REST. But, more importantly, I have included a pass through to the BitBucket API REST service on ASP.NET Core which demonstrates how to include the clientaccesspolicy for Silverlight. It's all in this Git repo:

https://bitbucket.org/MelbourneDeveloper/restclient-.net

The NuGet for the library is 
Install-Package RestClient.NET